# Group of checkbox in excel

Tags: excel, checkbox

I am creating an Excel form and I need to add a group of checkboxes all linked to the same cell. The idea is that the value of the linked cell should be the sum of the checkboxes ticked in the group.

I've searched and only found tutorials of one checkbox linked to one cell.

If I link more than one checkbox to the same cell then all are set or reset at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the 1:1 mapping of checkbox to cell. The value in the cell will be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. These are boolean values, so the TRUE is actually the value `1` and the FALSE is actually the value `0`.

If you have 10 checkboxes, map them to `A1:A10`. In A11 use `=SUM(A1:A10)` and you will have the total of checked checkboxes. Excel has billions of cells per tab and a nearly endless limit of tabs in a workbook, so don't be afraid to use some of them to store your individual checkbox values.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant solution but may spark some ideas.  Perhaps put some code handling in the Worksheet_Change event as follows

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

With UserForm1
    If Target = Range("C2") Then
        Select Case Target
            Case Is = 1
                .CheckBox1.Value = True
                .CheckBox2.Value = False
                .CheckBox3.Value = False
            Case Is = 2
                .CheckBox1.Value = False
                .CheckBox2.Value = True
                .CheckBox3.Value = False
            Case Is = 3
                .CheckBox1.Value = False
                .CheckBox2.Value = False
                .CheckBox3.Value = True
        End Select
    End If
End With
```

End Sub